# Differences in meaning and formality of "when/if + verb(ing)" and "when/if + one + verb(s)"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, formality

I searched but couldn't find an answer because I don't know the relevant grammatical terms, unfortunately. Sorry if it has already been answered.

I am wondering about the difference between the two forms "when/if + verb(ing)" and "when/if + one + verb(s)". Two examples would be:

> Of the 256 forms of syllogisms, only 24 are valid, or, by another standard, even only 15 when additionally excluding those that commit the existential fallacy.
>
> Of the 256 forms of syllogisms, only 24 are valid, or, by another standard, even only 15 when one additionally excludes those that commit the existential fallacy.

> This technology is particularly widespread when entering data in online forms.
> This technology is particularly widespread when one enters data in online forms.

Is there a difference in meaning between the two forms? And if not, which is more formal?

(If it matters: The use case would be statements about established issues in the context of a thesis (while also trying to avoid "you" or constructions with passive voice).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GrammarQuizzes](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-12.html#:%7E:text=A%20clause%20followed%20by%20before,other%20important%20information%20is%20lost.&text=while%20walking%20outside.) explains that

> A clause followed by ***before, after, when, while*** or **since** can be complemented by a *nonfinite gerund clause*
>
> 1. ***if the reference —person, animal, entity doing the action— remains clear*** (i.e., the subject of both clauses is the same) and
> 2. if no other important information is lost.

Although normally the *when + gerund* structure does sound more formal in your two examples, it is not grammatically acceptable because the subject of the verb in the gerund does not coincide to the subject of the main clause.

For example

> ***This technology*** is particularly widespread ***when entering*** data in online forms.

*This technology* is subject of the main clause, but it is not the agent of ***entering***. So the use of pronoun *one* is more correct. If you want to avoid using *one*, then you could get round it by using the passive:

> This technology is particularly widespread when ***data are entered*** in online forms.

As [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passives-with-and-without-an-agent) explains

> Passive structures without an agent are very common. We use these structures when an agent is not important, or is unknown or obvious:
>
> - The *data was analysed* and the *results have just been published*.

Comment: It's "the law of unintended consequences". Because of the attempt to write "better" formal text by avoiding passive constructions, the OP ends up coming out with the (to me, much more egregious) syntax error (no suitable explicitly identified *subject* for ***when entering***).

Comment: @fev : That clears everything up, great. Thanks for the comprehensive response.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : You are so right. These are habits, for in my native language it is often discouraged to use the passive or "you/one" in such texts. A teacher would almost always comment on my last sentence with "Discouraged by whom?". Always name the culprit, or so they say. Anyway, thanks for your comment. I guess I'll work on my fears of the passive.

Comment: @JohnnySilverhand: That's interesting! I always thought the tendency to over-use passive verb forms was specifically a feature of (relatively boring) "formal **English**" - made far worse by *less competent* writers trying to imitate the preferred style of professional writers. But don't be put off by a hidebound pedant teacher asking "Discouraged by whom?" (***who***, in my "non-PC" universe! :). That's just a cheap shot - to which the correct answer is ***I don't care! And nor should my readers! That's why I used the passive in the first place!***

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Even more, when referring to your own work, the use of "I" or "we" is discouraged (or, if you will: hidebound pedant teachers discourage) since it supposedly sounds subjective and unscientific (while this does not seem to apply to other subjects). This leads to constructions like "The author of this paper...", which somehow evokes feelings of multiple personality disorder.
With regard to English, I will take your advice to heart and try to make friends with the passive voice. :)

Comment: Now that I see it, I think my construction "when referring to your own work" makes the same mistake as before since "the use of 'I' or 'we'" seems to be the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Tsk! - *"when referring to **one's** own work"* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers : :-)